# About C0 semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let X is Banach space. Let T(t) is a semigroup on X.(t≧0)If there exists M≧1,ω≧0, will T(t) become a C0 semigroup?
I know the converse holds true, but
I'm not sure about this proposition.
I would be glad to have a proof if it is valid, and a counterexample if it is not.